# What is __XSI_VISIBLE?

Tags: gcc, arm, eabi

I was working on a C/C++ project for an embedded system that uses `gcc-arm-none-eabi-8-2019-q3-update` as a compiler.

I added the use of the `strptime` function of `time.h` but initially it was undefined and I found in the compiler inclusions:

```
#if __XSI_VISIBLE
 ...strptime...
#endif
```

So, I solved the problem with:

```
#undef __XSI_VISIBLE
#define __XSI_VISIBLE 1
#include <time.h>
#undef __XSI_VISIBLE
#define __XSI_VISIBLE 0
```

Now it works BUT:

- What have I done?
- What is __XSI_VISIBLE?
- What is it for?
- Why does this compiler keep it by default at 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/:

> The X/Open System Interfaces (XSI) option is the core application programming interface for C and sh programming for systems conforming to the Single UNIX Specification. This is a superset of the mandatory requirements for conformance to POSIX.1-2017.

The `__XSI_VISIBLE` macro makes visible extensions to "vanilla" POSIX interfaces, which otherwise would be forbidden to be in the name space. Remember that C language standards like ISO C and POSIX permit the application to define all non-standard identifiers (in ISO C and "vanilla" POSIX, `strptime` is not reserved, you can write a function with that name and have it not interfere). By defining so-called *feature test macros* you extend the set of standard identifiers and reduce those available to define by the application programmer.

Your compiler keeps it at 0 because the implementation vendor chose that it is the application programmer's job to enable XSI when s/he wants it. Application programmers do this by defining the desired feature test macros before header inclusion, e.g. with

```
#define _POSIX_SOURCE
#define __XSI_VISIBLE 1
#include <time.h>
```

or pass `-D__XSI_VISIBLE=1` to the compiler.

Comment: *"The __XSI_VISIBLE macro makes visible extensions to vanilla POSIX interfaces, which otherwise would be forbidden to be in the name space. "* Do you have a source for this? I've noticed that __XSI_VISIBLE isn't in the list at https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Feature-Test-Macros.html, and it isn't mentioned at the URL that this question links to.

Comment: @AJM Well, the "source" if you want to call it that is the ISO C Standard, which forbids name space pollution and the Opengroup's chosen name "XSI", and the "VISIBLE" part of the macro name. I wouldn't trust GNU's Feature-Test-Macros.html to be complete at all times for all architectures.

Answer (score 0):

The correct defs to use are `-D_XOPEN_SOURCE=1` and `-D_GNU_SOURCE=1`. These are used to conditionally define `__XSI_VISIBLE` and `__GNU_VISIBLE` respectively in `<sys/features.h>`. Defining `__XSI_VISIBLE` and `__GNU_VISIBLE` will not always work because they are overridden in `<sys/features.h>`.